# Android tablayout is not changing when the orientation changes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a simple TabLayout in my Android app which is different in landscape and portait modes.

I have defined them with the same name in res/layout/myLayout.xml and res/layout-land/myLayout.xml

The app works fine when launched only in potrait or only in landscape. The problem is when the screen rotation in the device is enabled.

App launched in potrait mode continues having the same layout in landscape mode when the screen is rotated to potrait (Expected result would be that the layout for portait would be pickedup when screen is rotated.) and vise versa for landscape mode.

The activity is not killed and restarted when the device is rotated.

I feel there is something simple that I am missing. Appreciate your help and time.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add in  in manifest:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

and code for the activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    yourFunc();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    yourFunc();
}

private void yourFunc(){}
```